# Problem with redcar installation

Tags: installation, text-editor

I tried to install redcar by following instructions from [here](https://github.com/redcar/redcar/wiki/installation). I installed Jruby as it was mentioned, but when I tried to run this command:

```
jruby -S bundle install
```

I get error like this:

```
jruby: No such file, directory, or command -- bundle
```

#### Edit:

I tried even running :

```
 sudo gem install redcar
```

(after installing required packages), which gives a warning:

```
WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec'
```

And then proceeds like this:

```
Successfully installed redcar-0.13
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for redcar-0.13...
Installing RDoc documentation for redcar-0.13...
```

And got stopped!

I'm very new to Ubuntu, I don't know what this error mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in terminal:

```
cd var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/
```

then

```
sudo vim redcar-0.13.gemspec
```

use down arrow key and search:

```
s.add_dependency(%q<cucumber>, ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f6c7dc26938> 1.1.2"])
```

replace with:

```
s.add_dependency(%q<cucumber>, [">=1.1.2"])
```

if u like add terminal command, then go to /usr/bin and:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/gem/1.8/bin/redcar redcar
```

then u can open redcar from your folder project:

```
cd ~/myProject
redcar .
```

if you get permission error like this:

```
1.8/gems/redcar-0.13/lib/redcar.rb:300:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/
```

do it:

```
cd ~/
sudo chmod -R 777 .redcar/
```